# How can I add/subtract to one axis on a control's location in a form?

Tags: vb.net

I know I can do .Location = new Point(x,y) but how can I add or subtract the value of strictly the X or Y coordinate?

Something like this?

```
lblTester.Location.X = lblTester.Location.X + 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblTester.Location = new Point(lblTester.Location.X + 100, lblTester.Location.Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

What olaf suggests should work, and this should work too:

```
    lblTester.Top += 100 'Move Down
    lblTester.Top -= 100 'Move Up
    lblTester.Left += 100 'Move Right
    lblTester.Left -= 100 'Move Left
```